# How to extract text from HTML (after certain string)

Tags: python, html, xpath

I have the following HTML:

```
<li class="group-ib medium-gap line-120 vertical-offset-10">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-right font-bold font-95 text-primary text-dark">
        ::before
    </i>
    <span>
        abc: 
        <b class="text-primary text-dark">st1</b>
    </span>
</li>
```

And I want to extract `str1` which always happens after `abc`. I was able to do it by using the `XPATH` link:

```
xpath('.//b[@class = "text-primary text-dark"]')[0].text
```

But the solution depended on it being the first appearance of this particular class, which appears more than once and isn't always in the same order. I was wondering if there was a way to search the `HTML` for `abc` and pull the subsequent text?

Comment: I was wondering how did you get `str1` with the xpath in your question? All you get is the element `i` where as `str1` is in the element `span`

Comment: sloppy copy paste, edited.

Comment: Using [0] in your xpath would make a difference only if the elements are in a list, since they are on different levels it would not matter, for different levels you need to use selector to identify a unique parent and continue from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe find the element that contains `abc`, navigate to child/parent if needed, get text.
Example of selectors:

1. Find any(* is for any tag) element that contains `abc` text and select any child.
   `//*[contains(text(), 'abc')]/*`
2. Find any(* is for any tag) element that contains `abc` text and select his `b` child.
   `//*[contains(text(), 'abc')]/b`
3. Find `li` element that has an element which contains text `abc` and select `b` element from inside it (inside li), use `//` since `b` is not first child of `li`.
   `//li[.//[contains(text(), 'abc')]]//b`

If you know `abc` then start from there, see what element is returned and if needed to navigate to parent/ancestor/child.

For more about xpath please see [w3schools xpath selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The following xpath should give the text you are searching for

`//*[contains(text(),'abc')]/*[@class='text-primary text-dark'][1]/text()`

assuming the `str1` you are looking for should always be under elements with attribute `class=text-primary text-dark`

also assuming that you want to get the first such occurrence ( ignore the other `text-primary text-dark`s )- that is why `[1]`

This xpath ensures that the node you are searching for those classes have a text `abc` before searching them.